# What is the most efficient path for a robot without turning radius?

Tags: linear-algebra, oc.optimization-and-control

I recently programmed a most efficient path for a robot going from $(x_1, y_1 , \theta_1)$ to $(x_2, y_2)$. The bot does a combination of turning and moving at any given point, based on the difference in angle between itself and the point. For instance, if the bot is perpendicular to the point, it should be entirely turning. Should the bot be facing the point, the bot should be entirely moving forward. This method worked great.

In my attempts to expand this to travel from $(x_1, y_1 , \theta_1)$ to $(x_2, y_2, \theta_2)$, I came across [dubins path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dubins_path), which performs this operation under the constraint that "turn rate is bounded." In my robot's case, the turning rate is not bounded.

I would like some algorithm to determine how the bot should move (or more specifically how fast the right and left side of the robot should move on [-1,1]) to perform such a path. My solution for the simpler case was $\langle sin(d\theta + \pi/4),cos(d\theta + \pi/4) \rangle $ where $d\theta$ is the difference in angle from the current position of the bot to the point, and the vector controls the left and right motor velocities, respectively.

For clarification, my robot is an "H-drive," meaning it functions like a tank. It has four wheels, each of which can be controlled independently (although there is no reason to control the front and back wheels of a particular side differently).

I would appreciate any help on this problem. Thanks!

Comment: http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jongjinp/papers/Park-icra-11.pdf